# What's the different between mget and pipeline in twemproxy?

Tags: redis, pipeline, twemproxy

I use twemproxy and every key is a `string` type. I need to fetch more keys at once, like `mget a b`. Key's length is 10. But tp99 of `mget` is not stable, sometimes there is no error, but sometimes error qps is 5 or larger.

Then I change `mget` to pipeline. In pipeline, I use 10 `get` commands to instead of `mget`, then the error qps is stable.

What's the difference between `mget` and pipeline in twemproxy?